# Inheriting ApplicationUser throws validation errors

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

My intention of below code is inheriting ApplicationUser and Implementing a new kind of a user called Customer. Information specific to this user needs to be saved in a separate table called "Customers"
Below are the ApplicationUser, Customer and ApplicationDbContext classes that are used

```
 public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
        {
            // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
            var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
            // Add custom user claims here
            return userIdentity;
        }
    }

    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext()
            : base("Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=ETrading.DAL.DatabaseContext;Integrated Security=True", throwIfV1Schema: false)
        {
        }

        public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
        {
            return new ApplicationDbContext();
        }
    }

[Table("Customers")]
    public class Customer : ApplicationUser 
    {
        public int CustomerId { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string Status { get; set; }
        public string BillingAddress { get; set; }
        public string CustomerFullName
        {get{
                return (FirstName + " " + LastName);
            } }
        public string Remark { get; set; }
        public ICollection<CustomerOrder> CustomerOrders { get; set; }
    }
```

Application builds fine but when I issue Add-Migration migration command from the Package Manager Console, I get this error,

```
One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:

ETrading.DAL.IdentityUserLogin: : EntityType 'IdentityUserLogin' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
ETrading.DAL.IdentityUserRole: : EntityType 'IdentityUserRole' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
IdentityUserLogins: EntityType: EntitySet 'IdentityUserLogins' is based on type 'IdentityUserLogin' that has no keys defined.
IdentityUserRoles: EntityType: EntitySet 'IdentityUserRoles' is based on type 'IdentityUserRole' that has no keys defined.
```

I saw there were Q&As in Stackoverflow where it says to fix the OnModelCreating method, but this project doesn't have such a method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why Package Manager Console was throwing a validation error was because initially by configuration, EF was reading a DbContext other than ApplicationDbContext. Below is how I solved the problem,

1. delete all tables related to ApplicationDbContext

Send following commands to Package manager.

2. `Enable-Migrations -Force -ContextTypeName "ETrading.Models.ApplicationDbContext"`

This changes the Migration Configuration to use ApplicationDbContext as the DbContext

3. `Add-Migration init`
4. `update-database -force -verbose`

Creates the initial explicit migration code and updates the target database provided in the ApplicationDbContext class.

When we want to change the model objects Inherited from ApplicationUser we can simply use the console `Add-Migration and Update-Database` commands without deleting already created tables.

Answer (score 0):

You actually need to do it the other way around. You need to add customer to your application user. So you do as following

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
    {
        // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        // Add custom user claims here
        return userIdentity;
    }
    public virtual Customer customer {get;set;}
}
```